# What is the meaning of “d'un autre pays”?

Tags: sens, prépositions

What is the meaning of this sentence?

> Ils viennent d'un autre pays.

Does it mean “they come from another country”?

What confused me here is “*d'un*”? What does it mean here? Should we use it for the sentence to be correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your translation is correct, and "d'un" is necessary.

"d'un" is the contraction for "de un". "de" corresponds to "from" and "un" corresponds to the "an" of "another".

Actually, this is a literal word-by-word translation:

"They come from an other country"

"Ils viennent de un autre pays"

and contract what has to be contracted.